# PHP switch case Connects

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I have the following code:

```
switch ($page)
{
default: 
    $page = 'error';

    // header
    require_once 'pages/header.php';

    // content
    require_once 'pages/error.php';
    break;

case 'index':
case 'login':
case 'register':
case 'profile':
    // header
    require_once 'pages/header.php';

    // content
    if (file_exists('pages/' . $page . '.php')) require_once 'pages/' . $page . '.php';


    break;

}

/*
* Footer
*/
require_once 'pages/footer.php';
```

Now let's take an example, and apply the following code to header.php:

```
if ($page == 'profile'):
include 'members/core/init.php';
if(isset($_GET['username']) && empty($_GET['username']) === false) {

$username   = htmlentities($_GET['username']);
if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
    header('Location:index.php');
    die();
}else{
    $profile_data   = array();
    $user_id        = $users->fetch_info('id', 'username', $username);
    $profile_data   = $users->userdata($user_id);
} 
endif;
```

And the following, to footer.php:

```
if ($page == 'profile'):
}else{
header('Location: index.php');
}
endif;
```

Site structure it's following:

**index.php**

**pages** (Folder)

=

header.php

index.php

footer.php

profile.php

But the problem its header.php and footer.php , wich seems to not make connection one with another, cuz i receive the following error:

**Parse syntax error, T_ENDIF**

How can i change code to make connection for header.php with footer.php ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you are mixing `if() { ... }` and `if(): endif;`, which is confusing things. There's no actual difference between the two, but they have to match up in pairs - you can't write `if ( test_something() ) { do_something(); endif;` This is documented in the manual under [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

> Note: Mixing syntaxes in the same control block is not supported.

The other thing to note is that each PHP file included must have valid syntax on its own - PHP doesn't stick all the code together and then parse it - so you can't open an `if` statement in one file and then close it in another. (I can't actually find a good manual reference for this; if someone knows one, let me know in the comments, or edit it in here.)

If you always indent further when you open an `if` statement or similar block, the structure of code generally becomes much clearer. If we do this to your code, and strip out everything else, we are left with this; see the comments I've added for where it's going wrong:

```
// header.php
    if ($page == 'profile'):

        if(isset($_GET['username']) && empty($_GET['username']) === false) {

            if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
            }else{
            } 

        // Closing with endif, but opened with {
        endif;

   // unclosed if statement at end of file

// footer.php:

    if ($page == 'profile'):

    // closing with } but opened with :
    }else{
    }

// stray endif, presumably intended to match the if: at the top of header.php
endif;
```

Comment: thank you so much my friend.. That it;s the corect answer.. Ty so much. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

There are two syntaxes in PHP for IF - THEN - ELSE. One is `if (condition) :` ... `endif;`. The other one is `if (condition) { } else { }`. Don't mix these. **If** you use the colon `:` and `endif;`, **don't** use curly braces `{ }`. **If** you use curly braces (recommended!), **don't** use colon and endif.

Inside your `switch` statement, I recommend you put the `default` at the end.

Comment: I recommend Notepad++, it's great. (If you wanted another answer, please be more specific. I'm not here to write your code for you.)

Comment: Im sorry for that, but i really need help for that part of code.. Im newbie in php, so i need help from experimented people like you. You say **There are two syntaxes in PHP for IF - THEN - ELSE. One is if (condition) : ... endif;. The other one is if (condition) { } else { }. Don't mix these. If you use the colon : and endif;, don't use curly braces { }. If you use curly braces (recommended!), don't use colon and endif.

In your switch statement, the default must be the last.** , but i realy dont know how to edit the code. Thank you for understand me.. Cheers!

Comment: It might be *good practice* to put the `default` case last, but it's by no means mandatory ([quick demo](http://3v4l.org/9vC1f)). In some cases it makes sense to put the cases in a particular order and then label one of them the default.

Comment: @IMSoP That's news to me. Thanks for pointing that out. Edited answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Put your default statement after all specific case statement. Other wise the default statement block will be executed and other cases ignored

```
    switch ($page)
    {


    case 'index':
    case 'login':
    case 'register':
    case 'profile':
        // header
        require_once 'pages/header.php';

        // content
        if (file_exists('pages/' . $page . '.php')) require_once 'pages/' . $page . '.php';


        break;
    default: 
        $page = 'error';

        // header
        require_once 'pages/header.php';

        // content
        require_once 'pages/error.php';
        break;

    }
```

**Edit:**

<s>There is no `endif;`statement in php</s>

Sorry, I learned somthing... Thanks :)

Comment: I receive the same error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in header .. Ty for your interests

Comment: There is no endif;statement in php. Just use If(condition){//statmentblock1} else if(condition2){//statementblock2} else{//statementblock3}

Comment: @Damodaran [Yes, there is.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: @HeikkiU you're absolutely right. however editing the answer itself is not appropriate.

Comment: Having the `default` case somewhere other than last has no effect on how the cases are evaluated. [Here is a quick demo.](http://3v4l.org/9vC1f).